# add_filter doesn't return false?

Tags: filters

I use last version of Wordpress and the plugin : Awesome Support.

In the code, I have this filter :

```
if ( apply_filters('wpas_show_reply_form_front_end',true, $post ) ) { 
?>  

    <h3><?php _e( 'Write a reply', 'awesome-support' ); ?></h3>

    <?php
    wpas_get_reply_form(); 
 } ?>
```

And I want to condition this filter, so in my theme `functions.php`, I use this :

```
// The filter callback function for answering a ticket
function wpas_show_reply_form_front_end_callback( $arg1, $ticket ) {
    // .... my logic to get total replies

    if ($total_replies >= 2) {
        // user can't answer more
        echo 'Cannot answer !';
        __return_false();
    }

    __return_true();
}
add_filter( 'wpas_show_reply_form_front_end', 'wpas_show_reply_form_front_end_callback', 40, 3 );
```

The fact is I can see my `echo 'Cannot answer !';` but the filter returns `true` all the time. Do I miss anything ? I want to condition my filter according to my logic.

Comment: You should use `return false` instead of `__return_false()`, and same goes with the `__return_true()` - just use `return true`.

Comment: Yes true ! Why ?! It's like both functions do the same ?! Damned !

Comment: `__return_true()` returns `true`, but you're not returning that value from your function. You would need to use `return __return_true()`, but Sally is correct, you should just use `return true`.

Comment: Omg yes ... I lost 1 hour for that...

Comment: Sorry @VincentDecaux, just got back on-line. And in addition to what Jacob said, you should only use `__return_true` or `__return_false` as a direct callback for a filter hook like `add_filter( 'some_hook', '__return_false' )`. But inside the callback function itself, just `return` the proper boolean without calling `__return_false()` or `__return_true()`.